# Why is CSS3 Transform rotate not working in this code?

Tags: html, css

I have used vendor prefixes but it's still not rotating for me in chrome.

Code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/sharmad/pen/HGyfF)

```
<div class="on">
  <span class="zocial-dribbble"></span>
  <span class="s" id="s">S</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=zocial);

/* zocial */
[class*="zocial-"] {
  font-family: 'zocial', sans-serif;
  font-size:200px;
}

#s {
  font-size:200px;
    transform:rotate( -60deg );
    -ms-transform:rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate( -60deg );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to the styles for `#s`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<div class="on">
  <span class="zocial-dribbble"></span>
  <div class="s" id="s">S</div>
</div>
```

or as suggested below add `display:inline-block;` that would make it too.

Answer (score 0):

Transforms do not work on inline elements, such as spans. As the others have mentioned, display:inline-block; will sort you out.